# How to make BxSlider hide all slides until the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I am using the latest bx slider for my website, but all slides visible and stacked on top of each other before the page loads. I have tried this one also
**css**

```
.ctaFtSlider{
   visibility: hidden;
   height: 0;
}
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
           ...
           onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
           $(".ctaFtSlider").css("visibility", "visible");
           $(".ctaFtSlider").css("height", "auto");
        }
    });
});
```

when i did this the bx slider got hidden after page loads.

Comment: Why did you make the height as 0? BxSlider may use it for dynamic calculations. If height is 0, the subsequent elements height also may become 0.

Comment: And if you want if for page load then wrap it inside `window load` event

Comment: can you explain little more

Comment: Remove `height: 0` and check. Also, if possible, create a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: have you tried using `display:none` and then in your slider load try doing  `$(".ctaFtSlider").show()`

Comment: @Abhi, the `height:0 ` is needed to stop the bxslider taking any space on the page, it will not conflict with dynamically added heights as they will override the style sheet when they are added and OP wants the code to be fired after the slider has loaded, not when the page has loaded, so adding it where it is is correct

Comment: @pete , I tried but its not working, still shows nothing after page loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a function that delays making a webpage visible during loading. I need it to prevent [`FOUC` (Flash Of Unstyled Content)](https://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-fouc.php), but this might work for you as well.

**Usage**

**CSS**

```
Add this rule:

   body { visibility: hidden; }
```

**HTML**

```
Add this to `<body>` tag:

   <body onload="delay(1500);">
```

**JS/jQ**

```
    // t is in ms | 1000ms = 1sec

function delay(t) {
  setTimeout('initFadeIn()', t);
}

function initFadeIn() {
  $("body").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("body").fadeIn(500);
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bx').bxSlider({
    pager: false
  });
});

// t is in ms | 1000ms = 1sec

function delay(t) {
  setTimeout('initFadeIn()', t);
}

function initFadeIn() {
  $("body").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("body").fadeIn(500);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>36646468</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <style>
    body {
      visibility: hidden
    }
    img {
      margin: 0 auto;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="delay(1500);">

  <section class="bx">

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/000/fff?text=1">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/00f/fc0?text=2">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/fc5/ba6?text=3">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/0bb/0ff?text=4">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/f3a/52f?text=5">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180/fff/000?text=6">
    </div>

  </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to set the slides to `display: none`

Then do `bxSlider.bxSlider(
  onSliderLoad: slide.css('display', 'block');
)`

Something like that...